# Rabittv on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: nautilus

Trying to install Rabbit TV to tried these command lines:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rabbitvcs/ppa
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-core
```

Install nautilus, thunar, gedit and command line pluggings using the following command

```
sudo apt-get install rabbitvcs-nautilus rabbitvcs-thunar rabbitvcs-gedit rabbitvcs-cli
```

all I get is a error on the last one  Unable to locate package rabbitvcs-thunar

Comment: please edit the question and post the error report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RabbitVCS is unrelated to Rabbit TV.

RabbitVCS is for version control: http://rabbitvcs.org

Rabbit TV, to which you refer, is for watching online content on your computer: https://www.rabbittv.com

It may be possible to get Rabbit TV working, but it will take a little WINE or such configuration.  If I get a hold of one and some time to play with it, I'll offer some instructions.